# Can't turn JSON hex color into Java string or java.awt.Color

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a class `Foo`:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Foo {
  private String color = "cccccc";

  public void setColor(String color) {
    this.color = color;
  }

  @FlexField(fieldType = FlexField.FlexFieldType.ReadWrite)
  public Color getColor() {
    return ColorUtil.getColor(color);
  }

  public void setColor(Color color) {
    this.color = ColorUtil.getHexString(color);
  }
}
```

a jackson color mixin:

```
abstract class ColorMixIn extends java.awt.Color{
    ColorMixIn(@JsonProperty("red") int red, @JsonProperty("green") int green, @JsonProperty("blue") int blue) {
        super(red, green, blue);
    }

    @Override @JsonProperty("red") public abstract int getRed();
    @Override @JsonProperty("green") public abstract int getGreen();
    @Override @JsonProperty("blue") public abstract int getBlue();

}
```

a jackson color module:

```
public class ColorModule extends SimpleModule {
    @Override
    public void setupModule(SetupContext context) {
        context.setMixInAnnotations(java.awt.Color.class, ColorMixIn.class);
        //other setup if needed
    }
}
```

and they get registered something like:

```
val mapper: ObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper
mapper.registerModule(new ColorModule())
```

when I return a `Foo` it gets serialized as intended:

```
"foo": {
  "color": {
    "red": 204,
    "green": 204,
    "blue": 204
  }
}
```

however when I want to create a foo from JSON it only ever creates:

```
"foo": {
  "color": "cccccc"
}
```

I have tried JSON that looks like:

```
"foo": {
  "color": {
    "red": 224,
    "green": 224,
    "blue": 224
  }
}
```

and

```
"foo": {
  "color": "dddddd"
}
```

to no avail.

I thought creating a new constructor in the `ColorMixin` class that looks like:

```
ColorMixIn(@JsonProperty("color") String hex) {
  super(java.awt.Color.decode(hex).getRed(), java.awt.Color.decode(hex).getGreen(), java.awt.Color.decode(hex).getBlue()
}
```

might help but no joy.

I am sure I am missing something obvious, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Foo` class has two `setColor` methods that accept different types: `String` and `Color`, and the `String color` field without an explicit `JsonProperty` annotation. Given that, Jackson assumes that `color` is a string, no `Color`.

Consider having only one setter method for the `color` field. Here is an example:

```
public class JacksonColor {

    static class Foo {
        private Color color = new Color(0xcc, 0xcc, 0xcc);

        public Color getColor() { return color;}

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Foo{" + "color=" + color + '}';
        }
    }

    @JsonAutoDetect(
            fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE,
            isGetterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE,
            getterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE,
            setterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
    public static abstract class ColorMixIn extends Color {

        public ColorMixIn(
                @JsonProperty("red") int red,
                @JsonProperty("green") int green,
                @JsonProperty("blue") int blue) {
            super(red, green, blue);
        }
        @JsonProperty("red") public abstract int getRed();
        @JsonProperty("green") public abstract int getGreen();
        @JsonProperty("blue") public abstract int getBlue();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.setMixInAnnotation(Color.class, ColorMixIn.class);
        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(module);
        final Foo foo = new Foo();
        final String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(foo);
        System.out.println(json);
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json, Foo.class));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{"color":{"red":204,"green":204,"blue":204}}
Foo{color=java.awt.Color[r=204,g=204,b=204]}
```